# How to fix React(TypeScrtipt) error "Invalid hook call."?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I got error: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." in react function:

```
interface Items {
  items: any[]
}

const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>();

const ItemsList: React.FC<Items> = ({ items }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const response = Http.get<Items>(url).then(res => setItems(res)) || [] as Items[]
  }, []) //something wrong with this hook?

  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item}/>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsList
```

I can't understand what I did wrong? can anyone show me where is error?

Comment: pretty much exactly what the error message says: you're calling the `useState` hook before your function component is declared.

Comment: Move `const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>();` right above `useEffect(() => {` and below `ItemsList: React.FC<Items>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call React Hooks from within a component, like so:

```js
interface Items {
  items: any[]
}

const ItemsList: React.FC<Items> = ({ items }) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const response = Http.get<Items>(url).then(res => setItems(res)) || [] as Items[]
  }, []);

  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item}/>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsList
```

See the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for more information:

> **Only Call Hooks from React Functions**
>
> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> - ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
> - ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks.

Comment: Thank you.I fixed error like  @Sam R.said, before your answer (you need also remove ```{ items }``` ), and now I have another error :)  "Object is possibly 'undefined'. In "items.map" line.

Comment: This is correct. It might also be worth you checking out this blog post about avoiding race conditions when making api calls within a useEffect hook. https://flufd.github.io/avoiding-race-conditions-use-current-effect/

Comment: @eu97 Not sure if it's of any use to you, but I use [use-async-resource](https://github.com/andreiduca/use-async-resource) with `<Suspense />` boundaries.